# windows phone scrollviewer jump effect

Tags: windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

how can I disable the jumpback effect of using the scrollviewer in windows phone app.

I simply want to scroll down the list of items I have, and not let it jump back to the top

thanx

Answer (score 0):

Nvm,

fixed this by setting a custom size for the scrollviewer